# in Ipod touch 4 (ios version 5.0.1), Is there a way to view volume as numbers and not as a slider?

Tags: ipod-touch, ios

I have a Ipod touch 4 (ios program version 5.0.1),
 Is there a way to view volume as numbers and not as a slider? I use it while I play the drums, and using the volume control as a slider is just not accurate enough( not to say not comfortable)...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to disappoint. It's not possible.